# Dell XPS 9360 - BSOD for twice a day for 3 months

Tags: windows-10, bsod, dell-xps

I run Windows 10 on my [Dell XPS 9360](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/xps-13-9360-laptop_service-manual_en-us.pdf) and all updates are applied. The drivers and BIOS is up to date.

Once or more times, my device will BSOD, with no error code, and the dump percentage stuck at 0%. It produces no logs regarding any errors and the windows event log also contains nothing. Device does not report any problems.

It has done this for the last 3 months, and does so seemingly at random.

I have replaced the battery since then, as I assumed that was perhaps the problem. The issue persists. The XPS diagnostics report no hardware problems

Today however I had a development. After the BSOD, I restarted the device and upon booting windows, chkdisk automatically ran stating it found problems, and for a couple of minutes, it fixed some errors.

Could this be the SSD beginning to malfunction?

Comment: Two things:  (a) make sure all drivers including BIOS are updated to the newest versions. Then (b) get the Dell hardware test application for your machine and run all the hardware test, particularly for the drive.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. all drivers definitely up to date. I ran the test diagnostic that can be run from the boot menu and it claimed everything was fine. Is there a more comprehensive one that will tell me if the SDD is failing?

Comment: If the drive is testing fine and all drivers are up to date, then consider a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation Link. Use the second link, download, and run in place. Use the option to Keep Everything. It is wise to backup documents and so on.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: Great. Is it possible that the chkdsk fix than ran after my last bsod was just random or a result of the bsod? or is that normally a sign of failing hardware?

Comment: It is possible, but not likely. If that was the cause, CHKDSK should have opted to run some time ago.

Comment: Perhaps.. "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl".. set to 0x00.  Perhaps you can get an error code then?  If it is failing to dump.. preventing you from seeing the actual error.  This might disable it.

Comment: In that destination in regedit, under CrashControl I see 9 entries, is there one in particular I should set?

Comment: Also, a simple solution may be if you remove then firmly reinsert the memory modules. I added the weblink to your manuals into the first sentence of your question. It's easy to try.